# Select value from time range dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of datetimes

```
tdata_df <- data.frame(timestamp=seq(c(ISOdate(2018,4,20)), by = (60*229), length.out = 6))
```

tdata_df

```
            timestamp
1 2018-04-20 21:00:00
2 2018-04-21 00:49:00
3 2018-04-21 04:38:00
4 2018-04-21 08:27:00
5 2018-04-21 12:16:00
6 2018-04-21 16:05:00
```

then I would like to get value from this time range table

```
time_range_df <- data.frame(start=c("08:30","11:35","15:10","05:00"),                     
               end=c("11:29","15:09","02:29","08:29"),value=c(1,2,3,4))
```

timerange_df

```
   start   end value
 1 08:30 11:29     1
 2 11:35 15:09     2
 3 15:10 02:29     3
 4 05:00 08:29     4
```

like this

```
            timestamp value
1 2018-04-20 21:00:00     3
2 2018-04-21 00:49:00     3
3 2018-04-21 04:38:00    NA
4 2018-04-21 08:27:00     4
5 2018-04-21 12:16:00     2
6 2018-04-21 16:05:00     3
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried to do to get your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sqldf` package provides greater flexibility to join in such cases. The approach is:

> Change time in `time_range_df` to offset from mid-night.
>
> Add a column in `tdata_df` to represent time elapsed since midnight
>
> Join both data frames for overlapped time since midnight

```
library(lubridate)
time_range_df$start <- as.numeric(seconds(hm(time_range_df$start)))
time_range_df$end <- as.numeric(seconds(hm(time_range_df$end)))

tdata_df$timeSinceMidNigh <- as.numeric(seconds(hms(format(ymd_hms(tdata_df$timestamp),
              format = "%H:%M:%S"))))


library(sqldf)


sqlquery <- "SELECT D1.timestamp, Q.value FROM tdata_df D1
             LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM tdata_df D, time_range_df R
             WHERE  (R.start < R.end AND D.timeSinceMidNigh between R.start AND R.end) OR
             (R.start > R.end AND D.timeSinceMidNigh between R.start AND 86400) OR
             (R.start > R.end AND D.timeSinceMidNigh between 0 and R.end)) Q
             ON D1.timestamp = Q.timestamp"




sqldf(sqlquery)
# timestamp             value
# 1 2018-04-20 13:00:00     2
# 2 2018-04-20 16:49:00     3
# 3 2018-04-20 20:38:00     3
# 4 2018-04-21 00:27:00     3
# 5 2018-04-21 04:16:00    NA
# 6 2018-04-21 08:05:00     4
```

**Data:**

```
tdata_df <- data.frame(timestamp=seq(c(ISOdate(2018,4,20)), by = (60*229), length.out = 6))

time_range_df <- data.frame(start=c("08:30","11:35","15:10","05:00"),                     
               end=c("11:29","15:09","02:29","08:29"),value=c(1,2,3,4))
```